# Previous version of document gets saved as most current version when the true most recent version is saved

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, versioning

I have a document library with versioning enabled (major only). We are experiencing an intermittent issue where while saving a document, a previous version of the document is saved as one version higher than the document that was just saved, both with the same modified date and time. Here's what an example version history would look like:

```
Version Number  Document Content  Modified Date
--------------  ----------------  -----------------
          5.0                "b"  12/11/19 10:20 AM
          4.0                "d"  12/11/19 10:20 AM   
          3.0                "c"  12/10/19 11:05 AM 
          2.0                "b"  12/09/19 10:55 AM 
          1.0                "a"  12/08/19 11:32 AM
```

In this example, when updating document version 3 with content "c" to content "d", version 4 gets created when the document is saved and simultaneously a version 5 is created with the version 2 content.

Comment: check if there are workflows or PowerShell or Timer jobs which may cause this issue. If all doesn't have, you can create a new document library and test like the original one, compare the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, the issue was caused by the user having multiple/corrupted Office profiles. We removed the profiles and created a new one, and the issue is resolved.